# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property mutable Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am working on an application using javascript to be able to add items to a mutable array. I have a global array `notes` that maintains these items. When a new item is created it is first stored in the database and its last id is returned. I then push this item to the `notes` array `notes.push(lastNote)` it works fine for the first item, however when I try to push a second item to it it gives me this error.

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

Please note the `save` method here is called through a redux saga. The code for the saga is:

```
function* workerSaveNote(action: any) {
    try {
        yield NoteService.save(action.payload);
        yield put(all());
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

```
let notes: Note[] = new Array<Note>();

const initialize = async() : Promise<Note[]> => {
    notes = await NoteStore.all();
    return notes;
}

const all = () : Note[] => {
    return notes;
}

const save = async (note: Note) : Promise<void> => {
    if(note.id > 0) {
        const updatedNote: Note = {
            ...note,
            updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
        }
        await NoteStore.update(updatedNote);
        notes = notes.map((i: Note) => (i.id === updatedNote.id ? note : i));
    } else {
        const newNote: Note = {
            ...note,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
        }
        const lastNote = await NoteStore.create(newNote)
        notes.push(lastNote);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it tell you what the readonly property is?

Comment: What's NoteStore? Also, shouldn't it be `put(NoteService.all())` in your saga?

Comment: @raina77ow, put is a saga effect that accepts an ActionCreator, `NoteService.all()` simply returns the `notes` array.

Comment: I know what `put` is, and that wasn't the question. Your code uses `put(all())`, and I wonder is it a typo or not. The other question (what's `NoteStore`?) still stands; ideally I would just debug this code with `stop on exceptions` flag turned on to pinpoint the exact place of error.

Comment: `NoteStore` contains a list of functions that executes database queries in this case.